# Deleted my thread again because of website link

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why isn't [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895595/video-bandwidth-detection-and-multiple-streaming-quality) valid?  How can asking with out any evidence be valid but providing a link to my website not be?

Comment: What question? Can you link to it?

Comment: Your questions were of poor quality. The continuous spamming of a link to your website (which was completely irrelevant) did not make it any better. Your questions didn't contain a sufficient amount of information to make them answerable. Nor did they demonstrate much effort on your behalf, and one was even simply utterly off-topic.

Comment: On my site it would be nice if people would be able to upload videos so content could be shared for free. What upgrades should I do to achieve this? Also does anyone know an algorithm to detect network speed or compression method for video files streamed across a broadband?

Comment: @Oded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895595/video-bandwidth-detection-and-multiple-streaming-quality

Comment: How can i ask a question without linking it? without any evidence all i wanted was help

Comment: @Alex Your English appears to be fluent enough. Why the garbled up question here ?

Comment: @Alex that link didn't add any relevant information whatsoever. And your question "What upgrades should I do to achieve this?" is too broad to even begin answering.

Comment: @Alex Why *would* you need to link to it to ask the question.  Why would anyone answering the question *care* what the site is, or need to see it?

Comment: How could they give an accurate anwser without evidence of a problem?

Comment: Seriously I think it was way to harsh banning me

Comment: By perhaps giving enough information to be able to answer the question, rather than going, "Look at my site and do my work for me"?

Comment: @Alex No person banned you, from what I understand.  You were automatically banned by the system because it determined that you had provided too much low quality content.

Comment: Um yeah ill just give them all my source code too while im there

Comment: @Alex If that would be relevant to the question, then yes.

Comment: @Alex: All your source code? Of course not. The specific code you are having a problem with? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: For those with the ability to see deleted Meta questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167742/why-did-i-get-banned-for-asking-a-good-question . Alex, your first two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827765/www-bytelearn-com-why-dont-people-upload-videos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893434/video-content-of-www-bytelearn-com were barely more than self-promotion for your site. Rather than learn when the first was closed, you posted again and again. You were not banned from a single question, but due to a pattern of ignoring site rules.

Comment: P.s. [Your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895595/video-bandwidth-detection-and-multiple-streaming-quality) (not a thread) has not been deleted at all. It's still there.

Comment: @Bart Well, one is still there, two others have been deleted already.

Comment: @Bart - I believe they may be referring to the now-deleted Meta question which was degenerating rather quickly.

Comment: I still think it was a legitiment question

Comment: What you think obviously didn't conform to the guidelines stated in the FAQ.

Comment: @Alex And we're telling you it's not. You can either attempt to learn why it's not, or you can hold on to your believes. One is going to be constructive, the other not so much.

Comment: The first two i agree  last one i dont agree with

Comment: Im open minded unlike the people arguing its not a legitiment question

Comment: If you're having trouble with a particular part of your website @Alex, you should at least attempt to provide as much info as you can PERTAINING to your problem.  Posting small tidbits of code also helps, as users here can try to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I was going to get into that but I wanted to point out where the problem was until i got deletede

Comment: @Alex Please please please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx If you then still think you've asked a good question, read it again.

Comment: Yeah I still believe ive asked a good question. Have you looked at the questions ive anwsered?

Comment: The questions you've answered are of no relevance to the ones you've asked. And you can believe what you want, the community thinks otherwise. Are they always correct? Nope. In this case? Spot on. Learn from it, otherwise it's going to be impossible for you here, which would be unfortunate.

Comment: How are they spot on. Ill agree the first two were stupid questions. the last I beleive wasent. You linked me to a site before when I do it im wrong.

Comment: Its not like I was jsut asking questions i actually anwsered more than i asked

Comment: Yeah...I'm out. You've been given enough information now by various helpful users. Read it, absorb it, or ignore it. Do whatever you want. Keep doing what you've done until now and nothing will change. Good luck.

Answer (score 12):

The entirety of your question was:

> On my site it would be nice if people would be able to upload videos so content could be shared for free. What upgrades should I do to achieve this? Also does anyone know an algorithm to detect network speed or compression method for video files streamed across a broadband?

This was closed as Not A Real Question which has:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, **vague**, incomplete, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Emphasis mine.

One of the overriding tenets of the SE network is, "Do your research".  The community isn't here to do your job for you; we're here to help if you run into a wall.  There is no effort shown in your question about what you have tried.  All we have to work with is, "My goal is X.  How do I achieve it?".  This is far too broad to be answerable.  What platform are you using?  Is it proprietary?  What programming problem are you trying to resolve?  You need to provide much more information in order for it to even be reasonably answerable, such as, "I'm trying to implement a video upload feature, but I'm running into a problem.  I've narrowed the problem down to .  Why isn't this working?".

As for the link in your question, you're using it as a substitute for providing enough information about your site in order for the question to be answerable.  If you have to follow a link to get enough information to answer the question, it's a *bad* question.  Based on your previous (and deleted) questions, it seems like you're spamming SO with your site link, so it's being deleted out of your questions (those that survive, anyways).

I'd recommend narrowing your question to a specific issue you're having trouble with, as "What upgrades should I do to achieve this?" is far too broad.  You should also show some effort in your question, show us what you've tried to figure out on your own.

If you can narrow it down, and make a good faith effort to figure it out on your own, maybe it will get re-opened.